# React - Invariant Violation: Minified React error #130. ONLY in Production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, materialize

Using React Materialize's [TextInput](http://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/?path=/story/components-textinput--default) component breaks my site only in production.

In development it works fine. with no errors or warnings.

I've seen some Stack posts about components not being exported/imported correctly. However my components all appear to be exported/imported correctly. The TextFieldGroup component is a default export and is imported as such, while TextInput is a named export and is imported using curly brackets.

The TextFieldGroup is a wrapper component the handles all the input validation and renders the Materialize TextInput comp.

I have narrowed the issue down to the TextInput component as I have tried replacing the TextFieldGroup component with just the `<input />` and putting the `<input />` inside my TextFieldGroup wrapper comp.

[Please my project with the issue](https://qupp.2112staging.com/). Click the login button to see if fail to render the page because its trying to the TextInput.

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Button } from 'react-materialize';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TextFieldGroup from '../../components/common/TextFieldGroup';
import { loginUser } from '../../actions/authActions';

class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        usernameOrEmail: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {}
    }
    onChange = e => {
        const errors = this.state.errors;
        errors[e.target.name] = '';
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            errors
        });
    }
    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const userData = {
            usernameOrEmail: this.state.usernameOrEmail,
            password: this.state.password
        }
        this.props.loginUser(userData);
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
        if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
        if (nextProps.errors) {
            this.setState({errors: nextProps.errors});
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { errors } = this.state;

        return (
            <Row>
                <Col s={12} m={6} className="offset-m3">
                    <h2 className="center">Login</h2>
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <Row>
                            <TextFieldGroup
                                placeholder="Username or email"
                                name="usernameOrEmail"
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.usernameOrEmail}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                error={errors.usernameOrEmail}
                            />
                            <TextFieldGroup
                                placeholder="Password"
                                name="password"
                                type="password"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                error={errors.password}
                            />
                            <Col s={12}>
                                <Link className='col s12' to="/forgotten-password">Forgotten password?</Link>
                                <Button className="btn-small right" waves="light">Login</Button>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </form>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}

Login.propTypes = {
    loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(Login);
```

TextFieldGroup.js

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
import { TextInput } from 'react-materialize';

const TextFieldGroup = ({
    name,
    placeholder,
    value,
    label,
    error,
    info,
    type,
    onChange,
    disabled
}) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <TextInput
                type={type} 
                inputClassName={classnames('form-control form-control-lg', {
                    'is-invalid': error
                })}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                label={label}
                name={name} 
                s={12}
                value={value} 
                onChange={onChange}
                disabled={disabled}
            />
            {error && (<p className="red-text col s12 no-margin">{error}</p>)}
            {info && (<p className="helper-text col s12">{info}</p>)}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

TextFieldGroup.propTypes = {
    name: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    placeholder: propTypes.string,
    value: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    info: propTypes.string,
    error: propTypes.string,
    type: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChange: propTypes.func.isRequired,
    disabled: propTypes.string
}

TextFieldGroup.defaultProps = {
    type: 'text'
}

export default TextFieldGroup;
```

I expect the page to be able to render the login and register page correctly when using the React-Materialize TextInput component.

Comment: Did you add `react-materialize` to `devDependencies` in your `package.json`? It should be in `dependencies`.

Comment: No I did not. It's only in `dependencies`. Thank you.

Comment: Does the error still occur if you upload a non-minified version of your application to production? If so, does the error include a line number?

Comment: I would give it a try. Is it a problem that locally I have three files`(/static/js/bundle.js, /static/js/0.chunk.js and /static/js/main.chunk.js)` and on prod I have only two `(/static/js/1.a0ef44a6.chunk.js, /static/js/main.139a355e.chunk.js)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to delete package-lock.json and node_modules on the server then run `$ npm install` again.